# How to refresh Div content on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik grid in a Div. During page operation this grid binds dynamically and holds temporary data. On a 'Save' button click, i am hiding telerik grid. This Telerik grid appears through partial view. On 'Save' button click I am not reloading or refreshing the page. So, the problem is that when my next transaction happens, the telerik grid does not appears. Because it is in hide mode. Hence i want to reload or refresh that particular 'Div' without reloading whole page. Is it possible. Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

[Refresh the div without reloading the whole page using jquery](http://crunchify.com/how-to-refresh-div-content-without-reloading-page-using-jquery-and-ajax/)

or

you can also look into AJAX